# Where was that blog post about misreading technical communications as a personal attack?

Tags: support, blog, behavior, company

Sometime earlier this year, there was a post from a Stack Overflow manager who initially thought her SO team had behaved unprofessionally to her, but, on later review of her messages (and some IM's), found that was not so.

I'd like to find that post so I can refer others to it as it was a great example of how technical differences can be seen as an attack where none is meant.

Comment: Why in the world is this down-voted so much? It definitely seems like a legitimate question.

Comment: I have made [a list](http://pmortensen.eu/world2/?p=89) to ease these kind of searches.

Comment: In this case though, they'd need *proper* search - and well, some idea of what roughly to look for.

Comment: [The HTTPS version](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2019/12/10/the-secret-index-of-all-stack-overflow-blog-posts/) in case it doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's probably this famous blog post by Sara Chipps:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/

Comment: That is indeed the post. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: I used it to apologise in the Python community where there was a lot of discussion about a language change. https://discuss.python.org/t/what-a-very-bad-day-at-work-taught-me-about-building-stack-overflow-s-community/2855

Comment: I know of other communications that was misinterpreted as an attack...